# Is it possible to trigger the lxpanel "Control for dhcpcd network interface" by command?

Tags: lxde

Is it possible to trigger the appearance of the lxpanel for Control for the dhcpcd network interface or any other panels of the lxde-profile?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Thanks for your comment @KGIII about the need to explain further.

I'm working with the Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) OS. By default there is - for example - the possibility to use the LXDE-panel for network settings. I want to know, if i can call this UI-Panel by command somehow, to open it in a in a own written software by pressing a button.

[image: Screenshot of the network panel i mean]

Update:

Sometimes it helps a lot to read the manual. There I found the command `lxpanelctl`.
In ~/.config/lxpanel/Profilename you are able to find out the config for the bar and panels on it. Sadly the call of `lxpanelctl dhcpcdui` is not bringing the expected result, but it seems It's bringing me near it.
I also found someone having the same question two years ago :)
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68149/open-the-network-list-with-command-line/68150

Comment: I'm sending a signal to open it anyway, but I don't know how to figure it out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not understanding your question. (I'm one of the few that still uses Lubuntu/LXDE.) Can you explain it better by [editing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/623427/edit) your question to elaborate? If so, ping me with "@KGIII" and I **might** be able to help.

Comment: Hey @KGIII ; thank you I'm editing.

Comment: I did some checking and I can't find a way to open that screen from a command. However, you can adjust the network with the terminal, if you're looking for a quick and easy way to change/set settings.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to check. I didn't find a way also.. I know there is a way of set settings through terminal, but i was hoping to dodge creating my own UI and use the one LX has.

Comment: You might find something [here](https://github.com/lxde/lxpanel/tree/master/), but I'm not a competent programmer and am unable to help beyond that.